# undefined reference to mmap and munmap

Tags: c++, windows, unix, cygwin, mmap

I'm totally newbie in UNIX project compiling. I need help or advice in using of Cygwin. An errors on "MAKE" command make me upset:

```
/player_module.cpp:96: undefined reference to `mmap'
/player_module.cpp:136: undefined reference to `munmap'
```

player_module.cpp has includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
```

Invocation code looks like:

```
dump_start = mmap( NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fileno( file ), 0 );
munmap( dump_start, sb.st_size );
```

As far as I understand the problem is with sys/mman.h include, but I don't have any clue how to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated.

PS. I don't know anything about UNIX, GCC or things like that, because I do only windows stuff.

Comment: How are you linking your binary?

Comment: "undefined reference" is a linker error - you're not linking to a library you should be. I don't know Unix well enough to tell you which one, though.

Comment: This is no different for Windows, down to the precise wording of the linker error. Apparently, [Visual Studio does Rot the Mind](http://www.charlespetzold.com/etc/doesvisualstudiorotthemind.html).

Comment: @Void Good question. Prior to try cygwin, I have got installed Mingw and created Path Variables as many as I can. So actually this question relates to Mingw linker not to cygwin (crap I'm totally confused). Now I deleted all mingw variables and try to install cygwin Devel package. I hope cygwin is clever enough to resolve necessary dependence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `-lrt` to your link command.

Comment: Maybe I can try, but i suppose "MAKE" command should do everything by itself. If I'm wrong than what the purpose of MAKEFILE ?

Comment: That's easy to try and if it works it will obviously have been worth the effort. You're totally wrong about make doing it for you. You have to tell make where to look for stuff, what are the dependencies (many are implied), etc, etc. Did you run `./configure` before running make? If the package you're building has a `./configure` script included, AND if you're lucky (especially in cywin/mingw), it may setup your makefile with the correct variables and then it should just work. Good luck!